# Creating Identity Matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to create identity matrices of different sizes, and I'm able to do so on a smaller scale like so:

```
> x <- matrix(cbind(c(1,0), c(0,1)), 2)
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
```

And like so:

```
> y <- matrix(cbind(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,0,1)), 3)
> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

However, it seems this will become increasingly tedious as identity matrices increase in size.

[image]

Is there an easier way to create *n*-value identity matrices?

Comment: `diag(5)` is a 5x5 identity matrix

Comment: @rawr: Thank you, this is perfect. I'm happy to mark it as an accepted answer if you put it below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

one (two) of the uses for `diag` when `nrow` is specified or when `x` is a vector of length one, you get an identity matrix

```
diag(5)
diag(nrow = 5)
```

or you could create a matrix of 0s and fill in the diagonal:

```
mat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
diag(mat) <- 1

## or shorter:
`diag<-`(matrix(0, 5, 5), 1)
```

All of these give me:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```